# tidy R way to import csv's using information from column

Tags: r, dplyr, functional-programming, tidy

I have a dataframe with rows from various calculations.  Each row has a directory and a label.  I want to read_csv a file from each row's directory and assign the label.  For example

```
dfs <- tribble(~dir, ~label, 
"d123", "dogs",
"c123", "cats",
"b123", "birds")

foodcsv <- "food.csv"
drinkcsv <- "drink.csv"

animalfoods <- mutate(dfs, fname=paste0(dir, "/csv_out/", foodcsv) %>%
  ????? rowwise/map/lapply/something(read_csv(fname) %>% mutate(label=label)) ???? %>%
  bind_rows
```

So the part in ??? is what i can't figure out.  The underlying files all have the same column headers.
Ultimaltely I want something like

```
id     consumed label
dog1   chow1    dog   #from d123/csv_out/food.csv
dog2   chow2    dog
cat1   chow3    cat   #from c123/csv_out/food.csv
...
```

In this case we'd have for example d123/csv_out/food.csv:

```
id,consumed
dog1,chow1
dog2,chow2
```

Comment: Provide samples of food.csv and drink.csv

Comment: '''d123/csv_out/food.csv:
id,consumed
dog1,chow1
dog2,chow2

Answer (score 0):

Try this `purrr` approach :

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

result <- map_df(c(foodcsv, drinkcsv), function(x) {
              all_files <- paste0(dfs$dir, "/csv_out/", x)
              map2_df(all_files, dfs$label, ~read.csv(.x) %>% mutate(label = .y))
           })
```

If I have understood you correctly `foodcsv` and `drinkcsv` are present in all the directories in `dfs$dir`. So for this example you will get total 6 files. You can use `map` to and read all the files for `foodcsv` and `drinkcsv`, add corresponding `labels` to it and bind all the dataframes together.